# ReferenceError in mounted hook in threejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js

Ive tried to import a js file with three.js code in it and it works fine in a "normal" html file. Now I tried to export/import the code from the extern js file and call it from mounted, but it just says [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: THREE is not defined".

Thats my code:

[image]

This looks like a reference error to me, similar to a missing package in Java, but why is it happening if the 'package' is used in the extern js file and how do I fix this?

Comment: might need to see that erde code, at least how THREE is imported and referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The imports in the external js file were missing